# Recommended way of mixing .NET and file context menus

Tags: c#, wpf, shell, contextmenu, windows-shell

I have a C# WPF application. It is designed to work on any and all files. Right now, it accepts 'input' by means of commandline arguments as well as drag and drop to a control in its main window. However, ideally I want people to rightclick any file/multiple files and have them be able to simply click 'Awesomify this'. (That's not the real name. :P)

I've got some experience with context menus from years ago, so all in all, it isn't too current. As such, I am looking for advice on the best way to implement this feature. All examples following are based on what I see using W7.

Generally, I understand there's basically two ways: pure registry, and registry + COM object.

The former has a certain elegance to it, since I don't want anything special; however, from what I can tell by documentation, these menu items always clump up at the same place as the primary file actions (*Open*, *Preview*, *Print*). However, I'd like my item to appear lower on the totem pole. If I look at my personal contextmenu for a random file, I'd want it to be at the 'spot' *UltraEdit* and *Malwarebytes Anti-Malware* stick themselves. Sticking my entry under `HKCR\*\shell\AwesomeTest` gets me my item, but no matter what I pick for the `Position`, I get two different extremes I don't like: `Top` puts it above the default item, `Bottom` puts it right above *Properties*. I want it inbetween *Share with* and *Restore previous versions*, which where most general-purpose tools seem to find a home.

Some more registry digging seems to point out the apps I wish to mimic use the COM object route. And that would bring me (I believe) back to native code. Which would then bring with it all the hells of 32-bit and 64-bit development I am trying to avoid.

Is there anything I am missing? Likewise, other than the [MSDN page regarding context menu handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which I have looked through and found to be rather unhelpful (as it seems to skim a lot without diving into the more precise details regarding placement and such), are there any good sources regarding this problem?

Another thing I've not been able to figure out just yet is how I can properly add IDropTarget support to my .NET WPF application yet, so information on that would also be welcome.

If anyone has an instant answer, well that would be nice, but I am mainly trying to find the right path to take without wasting several days on the paths that are dead-ends. Which there seem to be a lot of. :(

Answer (score 1):

IContextMenu::QueryContextMenu().  Shell extensions are in the domain of C++, very unpleasant in C#, .NET 4.0 required.  A sample project that uses it [is here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/FileBrowser.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that's pretty much the wrong side of the story. I am looking to put my WPF app in the file context menu at a specific spot, not to have my files by shown/accessed/etc from my WPF app. So far though, it seems the best alternative for that is to have 32-bit and 64-bit context menu handler dll thrown into the mix to show the item at the right spot.

Comment: (Mental note: stop delivering bad news).